# Инициализация статических полей во время выполнения в C#

Tags: c#, .net, jit

В классе со статическими полями во время работы приложения инициализация этих статических полей происходит только один раз, что логично. Но отсюда вопрос: получается JIT-компилятор создает что-то типа булевой переменной, которая показывает: был ли уже вызван статический конструктор или нет, и при каждом обращении к статическим переменным проверяет эту переменную? Так же примерно работает и NGen?

Comment: а зачем ему это где-то хранить?

Comment: Там не просто булева переменная. Там еще и критическая секция для синхронизации :)

Comment: @Grundy, чтоб потом проверять при обращении к статическим переменным, наверное. Я не знаю, поэтому и задал этот вопрос)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а про это можно где-нибудь подробнее прочитать на русском? И получается, что лучше со статическими полями не заигрываться, так как они несут какие-то накладные расходы? И вообще, есть ли возможность это отключить, чтоб я сам мог контролировать когда и чем инициализировать?

Comment: @Qutrix не додумывайте. Любой класс несет "какие-то накладные расходы" независимо от количества статических полей в нем.

Comment: Почитать у Рихтера, конечно. Загляните в список литературы.

Comment: @VladD, Вы про clr via c#? Хочу прочитать, но пока что интересует этот вопрос, не подскажите в какой главе прочитать? А то я искал уже и не находил, к сожалению

Comment: @Qutrix: Ага, в ней. У меня нет сейчас книги под рукой, но насколько мне помнится там должно быть всё, что надо. И даже больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [Рихтера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/10105), CLR via C#/4.5, глава 8, раздел «Конструкторы типов»:

> У вызова конструктора типа есть некоторые особенности. **При компиляции метода** [любого — *VladD*] JIT-компилятор обнаруживает типы, на которые есть ссылки из кода. Если в каком-либо из типов определён [статический — *VladD*] конструктор, JIT-компилятор проверяет, был ли исполнен конструктор типа в данном домене приложений. Если нет, JIT-компилятор создаёт в IL-коде вызов конструктора типа. Если же код уже исполнялся, JIT-компилятор вызова конструктора типа не создаёт, так как «знает», что тип уже инициализирован.
>
> Затем, после JIT-компиляции метода, начинается [дальнейшее — *VladD*] выполнение потока, и в конечном итоге очередь доходит до кода вызова конструктора типа. В реальности может оказаться, что несколько потоков одновременно начнут выполнять метод. CLR старается гарантировать, чтобы конструктор типа выполнялся только раз в каждом домене приложений. Для этого при вызове конструктора типа вызывающий поток получает исключающую блокировку. Это означает, что если несколько потоков одновременно попытаются вызвать конструктор типа, только один получит такую возможность, а остальные блокируются. Первый поток исполнит код статического конструктора. После выхода первого потока из конструктора «проснутся» простаивающие потоки и проверят, был ли выполнен конструктор. Они не станут снова выполнять код, а просто вернут управление из метода конструктора.. Кроме того, при последующем вызове какого-либо из этих методов CLR будет «в курсе», что конструктор типа уже выполнялся, и не будет вызывать его снова.

Таким образом:

- вызов статического конструктора типа C неявно включается в нативный код метода, впервые по времени выполнения упоминающего тип C в приложении, при JIT-компиляции этого метода
- на время выполнения статического конструктора потоку достаётся эксклюзивная блокировка, чтобы другие потоки не смогли зайти в тот же код
- другие методы (или этот же), пытающиеся выполнить статический конструктор снова, на деле пропустят его, это забота CLR (например, JIT-тер может затереть код статического конструктора после его отработки).

---

Интересный [пример от Эрика Липперта](https://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/), показывающий, что игнорировать глобальную блокировку не всегда получится:

```
class C
{
    static C() 
    {
        // Let's run the initialization on another thread!
        var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(Initialize);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
    static void Initialize() { }
    static void Main() { }
}
```

В этом примере происходит deadlock.

Что происходит? При выполнении `Main` сначала запускается статический конструктор. В нём запускается фоновый поток, который выполняет метод `Initialize`. При JIT-компиляции метода `Initialize` JIT-тер видит, что метод принадлежит классу `C`, что статический конструктор ещё не окончен, и добавляет его вызов внутрь метода `Initialize`. Метод `Initialize` ждёт глобальной блокировки, чтобы выполнить статический конструктор (точнее, дождаться его окончания, чтобы получить полностью проинициализированный тип). Но глобальная блокировка не будет отпущена, т. к. статический конструктор ждёт завершения `Initialize()` в `thread.Join()`.

Comment: судя по всему не стоит запускать потоки в статическом конструкторе :)

Comment: @Grundy: Дописал объяснение.